# Cannot set breakpoints in Meteor Node app with VS Code

Tags: meteor, visual-studio-code

I must have a bad setting or some misunderstanding of how VS Code works.  I cannot set breakpoints from my source code when I attach to a node process.

### Environment:

- OS: Windows 10
- VS Code: 1.10.1
- NODE: v4.7.3
- Meteor: v1.4.5.1 (Node: v4.7.3)

### Observed:

1. I set my environment variable `set NODE_OPTIONS=--debug=5838`. This will allow debuggers to connect to my program through port `5838`.  And this works perfectly for [node_inspector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-inspector).
2. I fired up my node server via `npm` in a command window (outside of VS Code).
3. I successfully attached to the node server.
   Here are my `attach` settings for VS Code

   `{
   "name": "Attach to Server",
   "type": "node",
   "request": "attach",
   "port": 5838,
   "address": "localhost",
   "timeout": 20000,
   "sourceMaps": true,
   "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/**/*.js"],
   }`

   Note: my workspaceRoot is at `E:\project\server`
4. IFF I have a `debugger;` statement in my code when I connect VS Code will open the file that has the `debugger;` statement and I will be able to inspect my code and set breakpoints in this file.  The file location for this file is `\1003\file.js`.

**Note 1:** I cannot set breakpoints in any other files unless I can bring it up through the debug session.  For example, I can bring up other files by selecting callers on the call stack.  But each file is from the *origin* e.g. `\1004\otherfile.js` not from my `${workspaceRoot}`.

**Note 2:** Meteor creates one giant `js` file: `app.js` with all my code concatenated in it.  There is a map file associated with it and I played around with setting my `outFiles` differently.  It is set correctly, because it is able to discern which *origin* file is associated with the breakpoints.  If I change the setting my breakpoint shows up in `app.js`.

**Note 3:** I also played around with `remoteRoot` assigning it to `${workspaceRoot}` seems to mess up mapping such that it cannot find `\1003\file.js` anymore.

### Expected:

1. I expected that VS Code would operate at least as well as `node-inspector`.  `node-inspector` comes up with my source tree and remembers breakpoints between sessions.  Very nice!
2. I expected that breakpoints I set in my source code would be loaded when I attached to my node server.
3. I expected that I would not need to put a `debugger;` statement in my code to be able to set breakpoints.
4. If I was unable to use my source code for setting breakpoints, I expected that I would see a directory of my *origin* source code so I could set breakpoints throughout it.

### Conclusion

I must have messed up my configuration somehow.  Maybe the debugger is unable to make the connection between my source code and the *origin* and I have to connect that properly?

I have been reading such good things about VS Code, especially the debugger that I figure I must be out to lunch somewhere...

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: I have no experience with 'meteor' but I noticed that you are not using a proper glob pattern for "outFiles". Please use something like this: "${workspaceRoot}/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/**/*.js".In addition you don't have to use "localRoot" and "remoteRoot" because you are not debugging remotely, right?. Why do you set "restart" to true? Do you really want to restart the debug session automatically if node terminates? (is 'meteor' similar as 'nodemon'?)

Comment: If you could upgrade your node to version 6.9 (or higher), you could try our  new node debugger by setting the "protocol" attribute in your launch config to "inspector" (but you will have to enable the new protocol on your node server as well by using the '--inspect' flag instead of the '--debug' flag).

Comment: Thanks Andre!  I changed as you suggested.  updating my outfiles and removing localroot, remoteroot.  I can still attach but no breakpoints get caught by the debugger.

Comment: could you please move the investigation over to github: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues
I prefer to have lengthy investigations there.

Comment: Thanks @BruceJo, your question got me further than anything else I've read in terms of being able to debug meteor on the server! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Officially there is a recipe see [VS Code Recipe](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/meteor)

You need at least Meteor 1.6+ and Node.js 8.9+ for it to work.